# $X$ is locally compact, $\sigma$-compact, $T_2$. $\mu$ be a borel measure which is outer and finite on compact sets. Then $\mu$ is inner measure.

Tags: measure-theory, compactness, outer-measure, borel-measures

$X$ is $\sigma$-compact then let $X=\cup K_n$ where $K_n$'s are compact. We denote borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ by $\mathfrak{m}$.

Let $E\in\mathfrak{m}$. We have to show that $$\mu(E)=\text{sup}\{\mu(K):\ K\subset E,\ K\text{ is compact}\}$$
Choose $\epsilon>0$

I know that (from *Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis*) there is a closed set $F$ and open set $V$ such that $F\subset E\subset V$ and $\mu(V-F)<\epsilon$

First of I observe that any closed set $F$ is $\sigma$-compact since $F=\cup F\cap K_n$ and $F\cap K_n$ is compact.

Now if $\mu(E)<\infty$, then $\mu(F)<\infty$.

So, $\mu(E-F)\le \mu(V-F)<\epsilon\implies \mu(E)-\mu(F)<\epsilon$ (note we can write $\mu(E-F)=\mu(E)-\mu(F)$ as $\mu(F)$ is finite here).

Hence $\mu(E)-\epsilon<\mu(F)$

This shows that $$\mu(E)=\text{sup}\{\mu(K):\ K\subset E,\ K\text{ is }\sigma\text{-compact}\}$$

Now if $\mu(E)=\infty$ then we must have $\mu(F)=\infty$, (if not then $\mu(E)<\mu(F)+\epsilon<\infty$)

Hence we have $$\mu(E)=\text{sup}\{\mu(K):\ K\subset E,\ K\text{ is }\sigma\text{-compact}\}$$

But we need to prove that $\mu(E)$ can be approximated by **compact** sets from below. But we have proved for only $\sigma$-compact sets.

It's not explained in Rudin's book. Can anyone complete this proof? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Now we only need to prove that
$$\mu(E)\le\text{sup}\{\mu(A):\ A\subset E,\ A\text{ is compact}\},$$
i.e. there exists a sequence of compact sets $\{A_i\}$ satisfying
$$A_i\subset E,\quad \lim\limits_{i\to\infty}\mu(A_i)=\mu(E).$$

Since $\mu(E)=\text{sup}\{\mu(F):\ F\subset E,\ F\text{ is closed}\}$, let $\{F_i\}$ be the limiting sequence, thus we choose
$$A_i:=F_i\cap(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^i K_k),$$
it is easy to see that $A_i\subset E$ is compact and $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}\mu(A_i)=\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}\mu(F_i)=\mu(E)$.

Comment: Why $\lim \mu(A_i)=\lim \mu(F_i)$?

Comment: @MathBS WLOG, suppose $F_i\subset F_{i+1}\subset E$. Since $A_{i}\subset A_{i+1}$, thus $$\lim \mu(A_i)=\mu(\cup A_i)=\mu((\cup F_i)\cap X)=\mu(\cup F_i)=\lim \mu(F_i).$$

Comment: Suppose the seq $\{F_i\}$ is not increasing, then we can define $F_i'=\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^i F_j\subset E$ and they are also closed. Then does it follow that $\lim\mu(F_i')=\mu(E)$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the WLOG part.

Comment: @MathBS Yes, you are right.

Comment: I think it's not true in general. Take $F_i=[i,i+1-1/i]$. Then $\lim \mu(F_i)=1$ but $\lim\mu(F_i')=\mu(\bigcup F_i)=\infty\ne 1$.